# Handling network timeout in Qt

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

When dealing with `QNetworkReply`, it is [prescribed](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11763) to use timers to abort the connection.

Here is my current code:

```
void ImageDownloader::download(QString imgUrl){    
  this->timeoutTimer = new QTimer(this);
  this->timeoutTimer->setSingleShot(true);
  this->timeoutTimer->setInterval(15000);
  connect(this->timeoutTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeout()));

  QUrl requestUrl(imgUrl);
  QNetworkRequest nwRequest(requestUrl);
  this->imageNwReply = this->nam->get(nwRequest);
  connect(imageNwReply,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(imgDownloaded()));
  connect(imageNwReply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this->timeoutTimer, SLOT(start()));
  this->timeoutTimer->start();
}

void ImageDownloader::timeout(){
  qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<" Forced timeout!";    
  this->imageNwReply->abort();
}
```

The confusion I am facing is when should I start the timer? At times I have to make around 50 concurrent *Get* requests from `QNetworkAccessManager` but since there is [throttling for maximum concurrent connections](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37530-QNetworkAccessManager-only-6-requests-are-executed-in-parallel-for-one-host), at times it happens that some of the requests get timed out even before they have been processed.

Is there a signal to know exactly when the processing for a request is started by `QNeworkAccessManager` so that I can start the corresponding timer only then?

One possible solution might be to implement a Queue of requests and have only the maximum possible connections to process but I am looking for a *cleaner* solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open [bug/enhancement request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3443) for the issue. I got to know about this bug from [Qt forum](http://forum.qt.io/topic/19182/handling-network-timeout-in-qt)

Comment: Third year passing for such a basic functionality :| I feel huge urge to grumble about that. That's a sign that I should implement a patch and post it..